# Force-Directed Drawing in Sprite-Kit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graph, sprite-kit, physics

I am trying to implement a force-directed drawing in Swift 4 with Sprite-Kit. I want to use Sprite-Kit because the built-in physics-world I think would cut out a lot of work.

As I understand it [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing), a force-directed drawing is obtained by utilizing spring forces (Hooke's Law) and electric forces (Coulomb's Law). According to [a Brown paper](http://cs.brown.edu/%7Ert/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf),

> To embed a graph we replace the vertices by steel rings and replace each edge with a spring to form a mechanical system. The vertices are placed in some initial layout and let go so that the spring forces on the rings move the system to a minimal energy state. Two practical adjustments are made to this idea: firstly, logarithmic strength springs are used; that is, the force exerted by a spring is:
>
> c<sub>1</sub> ∗ log(d/c<sub>2</sub>),
>
> where d is the length of the spring, and c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> are constants. Experience shows that Hookes Law (linear) springs are too strong when the vertices are far apart; the logarithmic force solves this problem. Note that the springs exert no force when d = c<sub>2</sub>. Secondly, we make nonadjacent vertices repel each other. An inverse square law force,
>
> c<sub>3</sub>/d<sub>2</sub>,
>
> where c<sub>3</sub> is constant and d is the distance between the vertices, is suitable... The values c<sub>1</sub> = 2, c<sub>2</sub> = 1, c<sub>3</sub> = 1, c<sub>4</sub> = 0.1, are appropriate for most graphs.

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to implement this, and all the implementations and tutorials I find are either in a different language (mostly JS), or––even if they are in Swift––do not use Sprite-Kit. I am not looking for a hard implementation, but instead suggestions and general steps to actually implementing this.

Additionally, I have different weights between different nodes, and I think that would manifest itself in a stronger constant for Hooke's Law (a tighter spring).

What are the general steps for implementing a force-directed drawing in Swift with Sprite-Kit? The two questions for which I would like very precise answers are:

1. Are there native objects/classes for forces I could use? If so, what are they?
2. How would I determine precisely what the magnitude of each force would be?

The result I'm going for is pretty much exactly [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

Comment: Question one is answerable (rigid bodies, constraints, joints and fields), question 2 requires a lot more thought and context.

Comment: @Confused, could I provide any information that would allow one to answer question 2?

Comment: You could, but you'd probably need to provide a lot of information about the type of force diagram you want (on each branch, criteria, etc) and provide a sample of the data, and the scope and size of the ways its displayed, and the means of interacting with the diagram.

Comment: And even then, it's a lot of trial and error and subjective judgement of what looks best and performs best with the data and within your intent.

Comment: The good news... yes, Sprite Kit has all you need to do this. After that, it's all a matter of starting from a branch and figuring out how to get its "leaves" to work the way you want, then adding more branches with more "leaves" and getting that to cooperate how you want, and continuing until you have all your data presented.

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion : Did you find any solution? I am trying to implement force-directed on iOS. but I found solutions for JS and Python not on swift.